# R data.table: How to optimize calculation of the value differences between two data tables for each corresponding group?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a lot of booking data (millions of rows) and want to calculate changes (differences = subtraction) of booking amounts between the same groups of different years that are stored in two separate data tables.

I can do this using the great data.table as shown in the code below but **how could the code be optimized (regarding performance and memory consumption)** since I am coyping data (tables) and have several calculation steps that could be done at once possibly?

```
# Calculate value differences for the same group of data in two different data.tables
cur <- data.table(company=c("A", "B", "New"), booking.date=seq(from=as.Date("2011/01/01"), by="week", length.out=12), sales.amount = 201:212, vat.amount = 11:22)
cur

prev <- data.table(company=c("A", "B"), booking.date=seq(from=as.Date("2010/01/01"), by="month", length.out=10), sales.amount = 101:110, vat.amount = 1:10)
prev

diff <- copy(prev)   # copy to keep the original data.table unchanged
diff[, `:=`(sales.amount = -sales.amount, vat.amount = -vat.amount)]   # negate the amounts so that the sum will be the difference
diff <- rbind(diff, cur)  # combine negative previous amounts with positive current amounts so that the sum will be difference
diff  # show raw data
diff[, .(last.booking.date=max(booking.date), sales.amount.diff=sum(sales.amount), vat.amount.diff=sum(vat.amount)), by=company] # calculate the difference

# Look at company "A" to verify the result:
cur[company=="A",]
prev[company=="A",]
```

The example data and the expected output look like this:

Data table 1: Current year's bookings:

```
> cur
    company booking.date sales.amount vat.amount
 1:       A   2011-01-01          201         11
 2:       B   2011-01-08          202         12
 3:     New   2011-01-15          203         13
 4:       A   2011-01-22          204         14
 5:       B   2011-01-29          205         15
 6:     New   2011-02-05          206         16
 7:       A   2011-02-12          207         17
 8:       B   2011-02-19          208         18
 9:     New   2011-02-26          209         19
10:       A   2011-03-05          210         20
11:       B   2011-03-12          211         21
12:     New   2011-03-19          212         22
```

Data table 2: Previous year's bookings:

```
> prev
   company booking.date sales.amount vat.amount
 1:       A   2010-01-01          101          1
 2:       B   2010-02-01          102          2
 3:       A   2010-03-01          103          3
 4:       B   2010-04-01          104          4
 5:       A   2010-05-01          105          5
 6:       B   2010-06-01          106          6
 7:       A   2010-07-01          107          7
 8:       B   2010-08-01          108          8
 9:       A   2010-09-01          109          9
10:       B   2010-10-01          110         10
```

**Expected result** (difference per company of the sums of each booking year):

```
   company last.booking.date sales.amount.diff vat.amount.diff
1:     A 1        2011-03-05               297              37
2:     B 1        2011-03-12               296              36
3:   New 1        2011-03-19               830              70
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice approach of @Jaap

Another way without binding the original tables together could be:

```
# aggregate tables by company
cur_co <- cur[, .(last.booking.date = max(booking.date),
                  sales.amount = sum(sales.amount),
                  vat.amount   = sum(vat.amount)),
              by=company]

prev_co <- prev[, .(sales.amount = sum(sales.amount),
                    vat.amount = sum(vat.amount)),
                by=company]


# join & get difference
cur_co[prev_co, c("sales.amount.diff", "vat.amount.diff") :=
           .(sales.amount - i.sales.amount, vat.amount - i.vat.amount),
       on="company"]

# fill NA's (companies missing in previuos year)
cur_co[is.na(sales.amount.diff),
         c("sales.amount.diff", "vat.amount.diff") :=
           .(sales.amount, vat.amount)]

# drop unused columns
cur_co[, c("sales.amount", "vat.amount") := NULL]
```

which gives the exact same output:

```
   company last.booking.date sales.amount.diff vat.amount.diff
1:       A        2011-03-05               297              37
2:       B        2011-03-12               296              36
3:     New        2011-03-19               830              70
```

Comment: Nice alternative! Two notes though: 1) this only works when you have two datatable and 2) the `cur_co` and `prev_co` datatables are new copies and thus get a new memory address

Comment: 1) True, that's what the OP asked for. You're solution is more flexible though. 2) Correct, these are copies but likely way smaller due to aggregation. Does `rbindlist()` prevent from allocating new memory?

Comment: @Christian Borck Thx for your answer, aggregating first is a good approach. I guess `rbindlist` will always allocate new memory since it must increase the vector sizes of the columns significantly.

Comment: `rbindlist` indeed also makes a copy. When only 2 datatables are involved, your approach is more memory efficient (especially with large datatables & relatively few companies). I just wanted to say that it doesn't prevent from allocating new memory.

Comment: @CristianBorck @Jaap I have done `system.time` benchmarks with 11 mio rows and a surprising result (all times are "elapsed" and the best of several trials):
My original implementation: 0,28 s
Christian Brock's version: 0,18 s
Jaap's version: 5,8 s (first version) and 2,8 s (second version with "shift" function)

The reason for Jaap's version beeing the slowest is ONLY the year function that is used in `by` for grouping.

My "lessons learned": Grouping by an expression is potentially expensive (slow)!

Thanks to you all for your answers anyhow :-) !!!

Comment: @Jaap To clarify for other readers: My benchmark results and result ranking would change significantly if the aggregated results would not be that much smaller than the original data ("high compression level").

Comment: @RYoda Because for your case Christian's answer is the clearly the fastest one, you should accept his answer imo.

Answer (score 4):

It is probably the easiest way to bind the original datatables together and then do the calculation:

```
# bind the data.table's together into one
dt.all <- rbindlist(list(cur,prev))
# set the key to 'company' and 'booking.date'
# the data.table is now also ordered by these two columns
setkey(dt.all, company, booking.date)

dt.all[, .(last.booking.date = booking.date[.N],
           sales.amount.diff = sum(sales.amount[year(booking.date)==2011]) - sum(sales.amount[year(booking.date)==2010]),
           vat.amount.diff = sum(vat.amount[year(booking.date)==2011]) - sum(vat.amount[year(booking.date)==2010])),
       company]
```

gives:

```
   company last.booking.date sales.amount.diff vat.amount.diff
1:       A        2011-03-05               297              37
2:       B        2011-03-12               296              36
3:     New        2011-03-19               830              70
```

---

For when you have multiple years, a better approach could be:

```
dt.all[, .(last.booking.date = booking.date[.N],
           sum.sales = sum(sales.amount),
           sum.vat = sum(vat.amount)),
       .(company, year(booking.date))
       ][, `:=` (last.booking.date = last.booking.date[.N],
                 sales.amount.diff = sum.sales - shift(sum.sales),
                 vat.amount.diff = sum.vat - shift(sum.vat)),
         company][]
```

which gives:

```
   company year last.booking.date sum.sales sum.vat sales.amount.diff vat.amount.diff
1:       A 2010        2011-03-05       525      25                NA              NA
2:       A 2011        2011-03-05       822      62               297              37
3:       B 2010        2011-03-12       530      30                NA              NA
4:       B 2011        2011-03-12       826      66               296              36
5:     New 2011        2011-03-19       830      70                NA              NA
```

Adding `fill = 0` to the `shift` arguments will result in:

```
   company year last.booking.date sum.sales sum.vat sales.amount.diff vat.amount.diff
1:       A 2010        2011-03-05       525      25               525              25
2:       A 2011        2011-03-05       822      62               297              37
3:       B 2010        2011-03-12       530      30               530              30
4:       B 2011        2011-03-12       826      66               296              36
5:     New 2011        2011-03-19       830      70               830              70
```

Comment: To bind the original datatables together seems a necessary precondition for me too! I didn't know `shift`, thanks for the answers, I will try it!

Comment: @RYoda Let me know if it works. `shift` is a fast `lag`/`lead` functionality implementation of *data.table*. See `?shift` for more details.

Comment: Regarding your first line, `rbind(cur,prev)` calls `rbindlist` if both are data.tables.